# android - how to load animation for all devices?

Tags: android, animation, load, smoothing

I'm developing a program that uses a simple transition animation when a new activity starts.
Animation sets for all rows of a list .

its brilliant on weak devices (like xperia mini and LG optimus black that are single-core) but on note 3 it has lag  and animation don't load smoothly.

Comment: overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation,
       R.anim.animation2);

Answer (score 2):

You Must add this Files to anim folder

animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-50%p" />
```

animation2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-50%p" />
```

and then :

```
Intent slideactivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class);
startActivity(slideactivity);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2);
```